# Ubuntu Operating System Error on Windows

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I recently replaced the graphics card in my computer, switched the case, and applied new thermal paste; that is *everything* that I did. Strangely enough, when I booted my computer back up, at the BIOS screen I got this error:

[image]

Now, I know that this issue comes in Linux when it can't mount a partition. The things is, my computer doesn't use Linux; it uses Windows 10. I did have Ubuntu installed on this hard drive at one point, but then I completely erased the partition in order to install Windows. I never got this error before, and it seems so strange that this only happened when I replaced a couple non-hardrive-related parts. What on earth happened?

Comment: Did you change from UEFI boot to BIOS boot? Or do you have EasyBCD installed to boot Linux which uses grub4dos based on grub legacy? The error message is from grub legacy. Ubuntu has used grub2 since about 2010, so either an old BIOS install or EasyBCD trying to boot. Believe the old error 17 is partition not found as you know.

Comment: @oldfred Well, it is indeed an older version of Ubuntu -- so it used grub, not grub2; I simply put grub2 because it's grub-related, and there's no "grub" option. But see, the issue is that the Ubuntu error shouldn't occur in the first place. I completely wiped Ubuntu from the computer before installing windows, and windows worked completely fine until I replaced those pieces of hardware; that is the oddity of the issue.

Comment: If older computer, is BIOS set to boot from first drive. And if you have more than one drive, you could have had grub boot loader in one drive and Windows boot loader in other drive. Then if drives not in same order, default boot drive changed.

Comment: You might have better luck reinstalling WIndows' boot loader instead of relying on whatever Ubuntu left over on your disk. https://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-the-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows is one option.